# Service only works in latest added dynamically create component

Tags: angular, rxjs, multicast

I am building a panel docking system like golden layout in Angular. I use dynamically created components to add the panels to the page like this:

```
@ViewChild('dynamicInsert', {read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicInsert: ViewContainerRef;

/**
* This is the onChanges for the dock component
*/
ngOnChanges() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.panelType);
    this.dynamicInsert.clear();
    this.panelRef = this.dynamicInsert.createComponent(componentFactory);
    this.panelRef.location.nativeElement.setAttribute('dock-tree-id', this.dockTreeId);
    this.panelRef.location.nativeElement.setAttribute('movable', this.movable);

    this.initializePanel(this.panelRef.instance);
}
```

The dockTree is an object that holds the different panels currently open. This way I should be able to implement saving the current layout to local storage very easily.

As it currently is my page has multiple 'docks' like this:

```
<div #dock
     class="dock">
  <ng-template #dynamicInsert></ng-template>
</div>
```

To communicate between these panels I am using a service. For example I created the clickService. One panel has a button that calls click() and another panel subscribed to getClicks():

```
@Injectable()
export class ClickService {

  private clicks = 0;
  private observer;

  public getClicks(): Observable<number> {
    return new Observable<number>((observer: Observer<number>) => {
      this.observer = observer;
      observer.next(this.clicks);
    });
  }

  public click() {
    this.clicks++;
    this.observer.next(this.clicks);
  }
}
```

Now when I click the button, the other panels subscribed to my service should all update, but only the last added panel updates:

[image]

When I dynamically add a new panel, which adds a new  element and attaches the panel, the new panel will be subscribed, but the previous one will break. When dragging and dropping a panel to a new place, which triggers ngOnChanges, the panels will have the correct value, but only the last panel will listen to the click.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the fact that whenever you call `getClicks`, the reference to the previous observer of the clicks is replaced with the latest observer. So basically you only have one (1) observer at maximum independent of the amount of panels created.

```
private observer;

  public getClicks(): Observable<number> {
    return new Observable<number>((observer: Observer<number>) => {
      this.observer = observer; // replaces the previous observer with the newest
      observer.next(this.clicks); // pushes the current counter to the newest observer
    });

   public click() {
     this.clicks++;
     this.observer.next(this.clicks); // only the latest observer gets the new state
   }
  }
```

I dont know why you opted to create an observable to multicast the number of clicks from a unique source, but this could be simplified by using a **Subject**:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class ClickService {
  private readonly _clicks$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  readonly clicks$: Observable<number> = this._clicks$.asObservable();

  public click() {
    this._clicks$.next(this._clicks$.value + 1);
    // some would argue that using a sync. value access in a subject is bs
  }
}
```

Now you should subscribe to the `clicks$` stream to multicast the number of clicks.

Comment: I don't fully understand Observables etc yet, so that's why. I got it working using the BehaviorSubject. 

I do think it's weird, because in training we have this application that has about 7 FilmListComponents subbed to a FilmService, and it just works. Is a normal Observable not meant to be subscribed to more than once?

Comment: An observable can have 0:N observers, thats one of the principles of the observable pattern. The problem is that your implementation stored only one (1) observer reference, the newest one to be precise.